# Configuration file for an application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration-files

Could somebody walk me through the ins and outs of a configuration file: what is it, how to make it, what to do with it.

I was given an assignment by my senior to have a configuration file that will do the ff: remembering the file location of an xml file and logging it into the configuration file.
For instance: upon opening the winforms, there's already a textbox with the file location written in it, when user open the filedialogbox and selects another file it would be written in the text box. user closes the winform. next time the user opens it, the last selected file location would be in the textbox.

Is this possible? My senior told me I could do this with the configuration file, as he is terribly busy, he cannot explain it to me further on what to do with it. Based on his short explanation, am I correct to think that this config file is like an XML file? Any examples you could provide for easy understanding?

I saw [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616065/Why-Where-and-How-of-NET-Configuration-Files) but I can't really understand much from it. Is there like a "Configuration Class (C#) for Dummies" out there?

Comment: You can add app.config to your application through these steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx and can access the value by this class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I saw the first link amd I've followed it. Now, I have an app.config created. 
Configuration Manager?

Comment: Have you seen the second link? If you want to read a value from your app.config can use ConfigurationManager class. Also you can use the @Loathing solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that contains all the user settings you want to save and then use `XmlSerializer` to read the file when the program first starts, and write when the program exits.

I gave up trying to use the built-in `Settings`. The main difficulty was trying to get the settings file to read from and write to the desired folder.

Comment: I think it's a bit advanced for me. But of course, this option is still available.

Comment: @Kurisuchin `XmlSerializer` is easy to use. Make a new instance of it, then call the `Serialize` method and pass in a `FileStream` and your object.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't exactly know how to do that. Or maybe I do with a little bit of a nudge, but I'm not exactly well-versed with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file is the file which comes with the exe after compilation.
In this file whatever values we are giving can be read from the application.
So if there is any change in the values inside the application we can set those values in this configuration file.
 For example, your application , the path of xml file is changing ,this can be set from configuration file
First right click the project file from your solution explorer and select Add new item.
From the window select Applicatiopn COnfiguration file and give the the name app.config and press ok
Inside the app.config . inside the config section add

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Xmlpath" value="C:\temp\xmlfile.xml" />

 </appSettings>
```

Add System.Configuration to your references 
Add using System.Configuration; to your form
In page load

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Xmlpath"];
textbox.Text=path;
```

Even after compilation the xml path can be changed ,as app.config will is accessible from outside the exe.

To change this path dynamically , you need to do more coding
check this link
1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14465/Specify-a-Configuration-File-at-Runtime-for-a-C-Co
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET
like